# What are these called in the User Preferences?

Tags: theme

I'm trying to customize my Blender Theme to make the colors easier for me to look at, but I'm currently stuck on where the Tool Shelves are located in the themes section of the User Preferences.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few settings that control the tool shelf theme, such as **Region Background**, **Region Text**, **Tab Active**, **Tab Background**, etc. Note that each editor got its own tool shelf theme setting.

[image]